# Play music using internal sound speaker over SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, motherboard, music

On my linux computer :

I can play sound from the motherboard using those commands, for example :

```
setterm -bfreq 440
tput bel
sleep 0.1
setterm -bfreq 392
tput bel
sleep 0.1
```

I want to do the same on the same on other computer motherbord : how can I handle this ?
I can do :

```
tput bel | write the_user
```

but it will pulse the same sound!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
{ setterm -term linux -bfreq 440; tput bel; } | write the_user
```

but the recipient of your fun would need to be using a virtual console to hear various pitches.

Comment: Thanks but the command "setterm -term linux -bfreq 440" will work through SSH ?

Comment: @anonymous: If, as I said, the "recipient" is using a virtual terminal (even if *you* are connected by ssh). If *they* are connected by ssh, then no, there's not any way.

Comment: `write` will filter out the sequences that `setterm` outputs.

Comment: @grawity: But it could be redirected to the terminal if the sending user has `sudo` rights. `{ setterm ... } | sudo tee -a /dev/tty1`